# How to show data in drop-down from database

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to show the data in Drop-down.
I want to show bussname FROM vendor_registration in postgresql

how it is possible

my coding is

```
<?php
require_once('/portal/scripts/define.php');
?>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnClkAddButtonServer(form)
{
    var selObj = document.getElementById('List1');
     var selObj2 = document.getElementById('List2[]');

      var i;
      var count = selObj2.options.length;

      for (i=0;i<selObj.options.length;i++) 
      {
         if (selObj.options[i].selected) 
         {
               var option = new Option(selObj.options[i].text,selObj.options[i].value);
               option.title = selObj.options[i].text;
               selObj2.options[count] = option;
               count=count+1;
               selObj.options[i] = null;
               i--;
         }
      }
}
function OnClkRemoveButtonServer(form)
{

     var selObj2 = document.getElementById('List1');
     var selObj = document.getElementById('List2[]');

      var i;
      var count = selObj2.options.length;

      for (i=0;i<selObj.options.length;i++) 
      {
         if (selObj.options[i].selected) 
         {
               var option = new Option(selObj.options[i].text,selObj.options[i].value);
               option.title = selObj.options[i].text;
               selObj2.options[count] = option;
               count=count+1;
               selObj.options[i] = null;
               i--;
         }
      }

}
</script>
</head>
<?php


$conn = pg_connect("dbname=" .MGRCONFIG_DB_NAME. " user=" .MGRCONFIG_DB_USER );
if (!$conn) 
{

echo "database not found";

}

$query = "SELECT bussname FROM vendor_registration";



?>


 <body>

   <table>
                  <tr>
                  <td >
                    <table >
                    <tr>
                      <td>Available</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <select id="List1" name="List1" size="10" multiple="multiple" style="height: 95px;  width: 225px;   border: 1px solid #535881;  background-color: #f9f9f9;" >

                    </select>
                    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td >
<table >
<tr>
                    <td  style="padding:5px">

                   <input name="add_usergroupsleftrightselect" value="Add &gt;" class="FormButton" type="button" onclick='OnClkAddButtonServer(this.form)'><br> 

                    <input name="remove_usergroupsleftrightselect" value="&lt; Remove" class="FormButton" type="button" onclick='OnClkRemoveButtonServer(this.form)'><br>


                    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 <td >
 <table>
 <tr>
   <td>Selected</td></tr>
 <tr>
                    <td>

                    <select id="List2[]" name="List2[]" size="10" multiple="multiple" style="height: 95px;  width: 225px;   border: 1px solid #535881;  background-color: #f9f9f9;">


                      </select>                     
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your database results and create a "option" for each in the select menu.

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT bussname FROM vendor_registration");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option>" . $row['bussname'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that, don't know anything about postgreSQL. The concept should still be the same though.

Comment: @jonnyobell:) i want to show the data in dropdown <select></select>

Comment: <select id="List2[]" name="List2[]" size="10" multiple="multiple" style="height: 95px;  width: 225px;   border: 1px solid #535881;  background-color: #f9f9f9;">
    <?php
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT bussname FROM vendor_registration");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option>" . $row['bussname'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

David,

The concept should work the same as JonnyOBell highlighted. Do some research on how to grab information from databases with PostgreSQL or else use a mySQL database (as it is preferred with PHP).

Once you have that information, you need to simply LOOP through the rows of the database and display the information you wish to display.

Also, `<select>` is a parent tag to the `<option>` tag. In a drop down menu, you must have the options tag nested within the select tags. Like this:

```
<select>
<option>Option 1 here</option>
<option>Option 2 here</option>
</select>
```

As you will notice, it will loop through those options if you follow JonnyOBell's instructions.

Good luck!